# Load More dispatch a function for render redux fields in component Error fields is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to dispatch a function in redux-forms after clicking loadMore , I have already fetched data from API and I just need to render slice of records at at time.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loadMore: (value) => {
            dispatch(value);
        },
}}

loadMore = () => {
        this.setState({
            pageNo: this.state.pageNo + 2,
        }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(this.props);
                this.props.loadMore(this.getData())
            }, 200);
        });
    }

<FieldArray name="getData"
                        component={this.getData}
                    />


getData= ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed } }) => {
        let fetchFields = fields.getAll();

        let displayFetchedFields = fetchFields.slice(0, this.state.pageNo);
        if (displayFetchedFields) {
            return displayFetchedFields.map((facility, index) => {
}
}}
```

**After clicking load more Error Comes : get.js:63 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined**

Comment: I think you need to dispatch some action with value not just the value. Also i think you need a return function inside the loadMore component. I am still a beginner in react so giving suggestion on what i understood from the code provided.

Comment: Yes exactly, can you help me into this , redux-forms

Comment: do you have the action and reducer you want to use?

Comment: Is the whole code for this component? can you please post the whole code of this component with import statements? I see this.setState which can be used only in class component but i dont see any class component.

Comment: Bro I want to cal a function only by clicking on load more, Yes i have reducers and action but i don't thinks it needs to be loaded here, because in that file i am just loading data into state payload

Comment: can you put your code on sandbox or stackblitz ?

Comment: no i can't due to confidentiality

Comment: i don't think you need to dispatch anything for that just maintain a state variable and change its value on button click, something like this onClick = { () => this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})} and inside the render function check clicked value and display things accordingly. Ofcourse if you need data from external sources you might have to use api fetch or redux but the overall idea remains the same. This can be one of the ways to achieve this and there might be better ways to do this also.